# Use CDN library in Vue component

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use [scrollreveal](https://scrollrevealjs.org/guide/installation.html) in my Vue components.

I included the script tag:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
```

near the end of the body tag in my `public/index.html`

I expect that within a single file Vue component I can do something like this within the script tags:

```
const sr = ScrollReveal()
```

However, Vue complains that that function does not exist. How would I go about using it? I can tell that it's loaded because in my browser console I can call this function. But for whatever reason it is not available to Vue or I am calling it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you didn't want to use [vue-scroll-reveal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scroll-reveal)?

If you didn't want to go that route, another option would be to import the library in the `<script>` tag like you did, and then add it to the prototype.

[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Real-World-Example-Replacing-Vue-Resource-with-Axios) is an example with Axios.